# Detener SetInterval con un botón

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este botón que realiza una acción cada 100ms pero necesito un *switch* que pueda apagar, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="button" onclick="setInterval(addX,100);this.blur();">o_0</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar todo a una función para poder guardar el ID que retorna la función `setInterval()`, luego desde otra función (activada por un botón tal vez) la puedes detener usando ese mismo ID con  [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Ejemplo:

```js
var invertalId = null;
var contador = 0;

function actualizar() {
    contador++;
    $("#contador-container").html(contador.toString());
}

function iniciarContador() {
    intervalId = setInterval(actualizar, 1000); // Cada segundo
}

function detenerContador() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="iniciarContador()">Iniciar Contador</button>
<button onclick="detenerContador()">Detener Contador</button>

<p id="contador-container"></p>
```